# Could you recommend me a program for putting logos on products?

Tags: print-design, logo, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a website/software that would allow me to put my logo in the cool environments such as in those. Could you please recommend me anything?

[image: cool written in design]

Comment: Are there any programs you've tried any didn't like or they didn't have what you wanted? Or is there a budget you're trying to stay in? Photoshop could handle all these scenarios just fine if that's an option.

Comment: @Johannes I'm primarily looking for a free program but even more important to me is for the functions to be automatic - I would have to work for very long to make such designs in PS.

Comment: It would be very easy with PS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bitmap image editor.

Free: [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/)

Paid: [Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html)

---

A mockup is a simulation of a product. *Sometimes* it comes with an *action* that prepares some steps (like adding some transparency, some croping and some deformations) And helps to automatize some of the process.

But to tell you the truth, most of the examples above are realy easy to make, knowing a cuple of tools on eaither program.

- Layers+Transparency
- Perspective
- Blending modes

You probably loose less time learning thoose than searching for a specific mockup that matches your idea.

Comment: I'm looking for a website that could put the logo I choose automatically on the products.

Comment: "Could you recommend me a **program** for putting logos on products?"
You could look for mockups. But if you do not want to do it, you could also hire someone.

Comment: Btw I have specified it as a *website* to indicate that I'm not looking for a photo editor in general and I had thought a website could do better, afterall. But since I'm not really accustomed in designer english phraseology I didn't really know how to name what I was looking for but your suggestion solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: "Promotional Marketing or Promotional Products" companies put your name on products. I call them the "Print your name on anything" companies because they sell: hats, pens, shirts, pads, calendars, cups, whistles, bags, tools; many many products, printed with anything you want. There are literally hundreds of these sites, and they will print art, photos, logos, text, whatever you want.  Vistaprint has a wide variety of products but if you just search for Promotional Products or Print on... you will see the companies.